# How to multiply a matrix by a scalar value in MATLAB under a condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, conditional-statements, multiplication, scalar

In matlab I have a matrix with random numbers between 0 and 100.
All numbers below 10 shall be multiplicated by two.

testmatrix = [1,2;11,90]
should turn into [2,4;11,90]

Executing conditional operations on the matrix is easy enough, but how do I reference the current element on the right side?

testmatrix(testmatrix<10) = ???*2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In exactly the same way as on the left hand side:

```
testmatrix(testmatrix<10) = testmatrix(testmatrix<10)*2
```

Or as [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) points out, you can save on computations by creating a reusable logical indexing mask:

```
idx = testmatrix < 10
testmatrix(idx) = testmatrix(idx)*2
```

This second approach is particularly useful in more cases with more complex conditions or where the condition is repeated many times or when speed is a major concern

Comment: @user2306536: you could also save the logical indexing mask in a variable for reuse: `idx = (testmatrix<10);` then `testmatrix(idx)=testmatrix(idx)*2;`

Answer (score 3):

What you need is:

```
testmatrix(testmatrix < 10) = testmatrix(testmatrix < 10)*2;
```

Comment: @user2306536: You should probably accept Dan's answer. It's the same and it's marginally older.

Comment: You are right. I choose Roneys answer because it appeared on top from the beginning, so thought it was first.

Comment: Doesn't bother me - they were basically at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> > A = randi(100,1000,1);
> >
> > cond = A <= 10;
> >
> > test = A(cond).*2